# Configuring globally NodeJS to Proxy HTTP request

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

How should I configure NodeJS **globally** to set a Proxy for all HTTP Request ?

- I can't use request module because I use a third party library using NodeJS Http.Client
- A cURL is working on my server, I'd like my server to use the proxy too
- I see an answer using [global-tunnel](https://github.com/salesforce/global-tunnel) but it's a 4year old library ?!

Thanks !

Comment: If you use `request` (or any library that builds on it), the `http_proxy` environment variable will be honored. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy

Comment: I would rather prefer nginx server for global proxing goals - it's faster.

Comment: tomalak me too :-) Vladyslav how do you proxy all request from nodejs to outside world throught a company proxy with Nginx ? I assume you have to hook outbound request somehow ?